# Running RsTeX on Linux

Tags: compilation, tex

I came across this interesting project [RsTeX](https://github.com/nadder/rstex) that was a manual implementation of Donald Knuth's tex program in C++. As far as I have read, the program appears mature and passed the trip test (tripman.tex), which was designed by Knuth for asserting the validity of code.

Unfortunately, I am not certain how to run the files. Have successfully compiled the code for Debian Linux; however, I cannot get even a minimal example to work properly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Hello this is an RsTeX demonstration.
\[
    a^2 + b^2 = c^2
\]
\end{document}
```

Running the command `rstex a.tex` produces the output

```
This is rsTeX, Version 1.1.7 for Unix (INITEX)
(a.tex
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1 \documentclass
                  {article}
? 
! Undefined control sequence.
l.2 \begin
          {document}
? 
! Undefined control sequence.
l.4 \[
      
? 
! Undefined control sequence.
l.6 \]
      
? 
[0] )
Output written on a.dvi (1 page, 128 bytes).
Transcript written on a.log.
```

The DVI file is essentially empty and only contains the following.

```
'TeX output 2023.06.26:1903'
Postamble starts at byte 88.
maxv=0, maxh=0, maxstackdepth=1, totalpages=1
 
42: beginning of page 0 
87: eop
```

The repository is not documented, but the following message was present in the Readme. Was the repository abandoned? It just seems inconceivable that after the author spent 100 hours (his own admission) he would leave the program incomplete. I tried using `rstex_unix`, which added support for environment variables to direct the tex implementation to the certain files necessary for compilation. There was still no documentation about this feature, so I did not know how to proceed.

> Notable omissions
>
> - Currently no path searching is done so all files the program needs are supposed to exist in the current directory. (See the Unix and Windows specific versions to avoid this).
> - No other files needed for a complete system is included, i.e. fmt files, fonts, tfm files macro packages etc.

**Question:**
Is there a way for me to compile a basic latex file on Linux using RsTeX, or was the project left unfinished? In particular, how do I specify the document class and import external packages?

**Edit:**
After learning about the differences between TeX and LaTeX, I now know that I wish to specify the macro file used by LaTeX and stored in a format file. I believe the proper environment variable is `TEXFORMATS`, but I do not know what else to do as it is undocumented.

Comment: Sounds as if you might want to try a plain tex file, e.g. `Hello World

\bye` instead of a **LA**tex file

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Could you please elaborate upon the differences? Tex was invented before LaTeX, right? I apologize that I am still rather ignorant of the terminology employed among TeX developers.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49/what-is-the-difference-between-tex-and-latex for the difference between plain tex and latex

Comment: LaTeX requires the e-TeX extensions ([since 2017](https://www.latex-project.org/news/2016/11/04/eTeX-kernel/)), while rsTeX implements only Knuth TeX, so you can only use the plain format with it (or else build and use an old LaTeX format, from 2016 or earlier).

Comment: (Also, LaTeX requires a "large" TeX, with increased limits for the pool size, memory etc — larger than the defaults from Knuth TeX, which I imagine are copied over to rsTeX. So even if you want to use an older LaTeX, you may need to fiddle a bit or even change the source code, to use larger limits.)

Answer (score 2):

When you say “cannot get even a minimal example to work properly”, you're using an example of LaTeX, which is a heavyweight macro package on top of TeX. Using LaTeX introduces two complications:

1. LaTeX requires the e-TeX extensions ([since 2017](https://www.latex-project.org/news/2016/11/04/eTeX-kernel/)), while rsTeX implements only Knuth TeX. So you'll have to either:

   - edit the sources to add the e-TeX extensions ([yourself](https://github.com/nadder/rstex/issues/4#issuecomment-1450844930)), which basically requires understanding the entire TeX program and e-TeX changes,
   - use an old LaTeX format, from 2016 or earlier.
2. LaTeX requires a "large" TeX, with increased limits for the pool size, memory etc — larger than the defaults from Knuth TeX, which are copied over to rsTeX. So you'll need to fiddle a bit with the constants in the source code, to use larger limits (even larger if you use more LaTeX packages etc).

Nevertheless, if you really want to, both can be done.

Get the source code, e.g. with `git clone https://github.com/nadder/rstex.git`

Go into the `rstex` directory.

Get an old TeX distribution (this is large, **1.9289 GiB**):

```
curl -LRO ftp://tug.org/texlive/historic//2016/texlive-20160523b-texmf.tar.xz
```

Copy over (or symlink) the relevant files: for the "minimal" example above, these are:

```
latex.ltx -> ./texlive-20160523-texmf/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/latex.ltx
texsys.cfg -> ./texlive-20160523-texmf/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/texsys.cfg
omlenc.def -> ./texlive-20160523-texmf/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/omlenc.def
omsenc.def -> ./texlive-20160523-texmf/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/omsenc.def
ot1enc.def -> ./texlive-20160523-texmf/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ot1enc.def
t1enc.def -> ./texlive-20160523-texmf/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.def
ts1enc.def -> ./texlive-20160523-texmf/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1enc.def
fonttext.ltx -> ./texlive-20160523-texmf/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fonttext.ltx
t1cmr.fd -> ./texlive-20160523-texmf/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1cmr.fd
ot1cmr.fd -> ./texlive-20160523-texmf/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ot1cmr.fd
ot1cmss.fd -> ./texlive-20160523-texmf/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ot1cmss.fd
ot1cmtt.fd -> ./texlive-20160523-texmf/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ot1cmtt.fd
fontmath.ltx -> ./texlive-20160523-texmf/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontmath.ltx
omlcmm.fd -> ./texlive-20160523-texmf/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/omlcmm.fd
omscmsy.fd -> ./texlive-20160523-texmf/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/omscmsy.fd
omxcmex.fd -> ./texlive-20160523-texmf/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/omxcmex.fd
ucmr.fd -> ./texlive-20160523-texmf/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ucmr.fd
preload.ltx -> ./texlive-20160523-texmf/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/preload.ltx
cmex10.tfm -> ./texlive-20160523-texmf/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/cm/cmex10.tfm
line10.tfm -> ./texlive-20160523-texmf/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/latex-fonts/line10.tfm
linew10.tfm -> ./texlive-20160523-texmf/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/latex-fonts/linew10.tfm
lcircle10.tfm -> ./texlive-20160523-texmf/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/latex-fonts/lcircle10.tfm
lcirclew10.tfm -> ./texlive-20160523-texmf/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/latex-fonts/lcirclew10.tfm
cmr5.tfm -> ./texlive-20160523-texmf/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/cm/cmr5.tfm
cmr7.tfm -> ./texlive-20160523-texmf/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/cm/cmr7.tfm
cmr10.tfm -> ./texlive-20160523-texmf/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/cm/cmr10.tfm
cmmi5.tfm -> ./texlive-20160523-texmf/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/cm/cmmi5.tfm
cmmi7.tfm -> ./texlive-20160523-texmf/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/cm/cmmi7.tfm
cmmi10.tfm -> ./texlive-20160523-texmf/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/cm/cmmi10.tfm
cmsy5 -> ./texlive-20160523-texmf/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/cm/cmsy5
cmsy5.tfm -> ./texlive-20160523-texmf/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/cm/cmsy5.tfm
cmsy7.tfm -> ./texlive-20160523-texmf/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/cm/cmsy7.tfm
cmsy10.tfm -> ./texlive-20160523-texmf/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/cm/cmsy10.tfm
hyphen.ltx -> ./texlive-20160523-texmf/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/hyphen.ltx
hyphen.tex -> ./texlive-20160523-texmf/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyphen/hyphen.tex
article.cls -> ./texlive-20160523-texmf/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
size10.clo -> ./texlive-20160523-texmf/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
```

Edit the constants in `rstex.h.pre` file as needed: I had to bump up `mem_max` = `mem_top`, `max_strings`, `pool_size`, `hash_size`:

```
--- rstex.h.pre
+++ rstex.h.pre
@@ -36,7 +36,7 @@ struct Array
 #define loc cur_input.loc_field // location of first unread character in buffer
 
 // <The following parameters can be changed at compile time to extend or reduce rsTeX's capacity 11>
-const int mem_max = 30000; // Greatest index in rsTeX's internal mem array; must be strictly less than
+const int mem_max = 50000; // Greatest index in rsTeX's internal mem array; must be strictly less than
                            // max_halfword; must be equal to mem_top in INITEX, otherise >= mem_top
 //const int mem_max = 3000; // triptex
 const int mem_min = 0; // Smallest index in rsTeX's internal mem array; must be min_halfword or more;
@@ -57,10 +57,10 @@ const int font_max = 75; // Maximum internal font number; must not exceed max_qu
 const int font_mem_size = 20000; // Number of words of font_info for all fonts
 const int param_size = 60; // Maximum number of simultaneous macro parameters
 const int nest_size = 40; // Maximum number of semantic levels simultaneously active
-const int max_strings = 3000; // Maximum number of strings; must not exceed max_halfword
+const int max_strings = 5000; // Maximum number of strings; must not exceed max_halfword
 const int string_vacancies = 8000; // The minimum number of characters that should be available for the user's
                                    // control sequences and font names, after rsTeX's own error messages are stored
-const int pool_size = 40000; // Maximum number of characters in strings, including all error messages and help texts,
+const int pool_size = 60000; // Maximum number of characters in strings, including all error messages and help texts,
                              // and the names of all fonts and control sequences; must exceed string_vacancies by the
                             // total length of rsTeX's own strings, which is currently about 23000
 const int save_size = 600; // Space for saving values outside of current group; must be at most max_halfword
@@ -317,11 +317,11 @@ bool OK_to_interrupt; // should interrupts be observed?
 // 12
 const int mem_bot = 0; // smallest index in the mem array dumped by INITEX; must not be less than mem_min
 //const int mem_bot = 1; // triptex
-const int mem_top = 30000; // largest index in the mem_array dumped by INITEX; must be substantially larger
+const int mem_top = 50000; // largest index in the mem_array dumped by INITEX; must be substantially larger
                            // than mem_bot and not greater than mem_max
 //const int mem_top = 3000; // triptex
 const int font_base = 0; // smallest internal font number; must not be less than min_quarterword
-const int hash_size = 2100; // maximum number of control sequences; it should be at most about (mem_max - mem_min) / 10
+const int hash_size = 4100; // maximum number of control sequences; it should be at most about (mem_max - mem_min) / 10
 const int hash_prime = 1777; // a prime number equal to about 85% of hash_size
 const int hyph_size = 307; // another prime; the number of \hyphenation exceptions
```

Now build rsTeX:

```bash
chmod +x ./build.sh && ./build.sh
```

Build the LaTeX format:

```bash
./rstex latex.ltx
```

This will create a `latex.fmt` file.

Put your example input into `example.tex`, and run rsTeX using the just-built LaTeX format:

```bash
./rstex '&latex' example.tex
```

This will produce an `example.dvi` with the desired output:

[image: output example.dvi from rsTeX]

Note that for almost any typical LaTeX packages you may want to use, you'll probably have to (in addition to making the corresponding files and all their dependencies available) bump up the constants further: some of them may even require changing some types in the source code, e.g. from `int` to something larger.

Comment: This is incredible! Thank you so much